# Concatenate string with specific separator at specific position in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to generate xml from from table with this sample data:

```
position  value
----------------
1.1       a
1.2       b
2.1       c
2.1.2     d
3.1       e
3.1.2     f
3.1.2.1   g
```

Output should look like this:

```
<1>
  <2>b</2>
</1>
<2>c
   <1>
     <2>d</2>
   </1>
</2>
<3>e
   <1>
     <2>f
       <1>g</1> 
    </2>
   </1>
</3>
```

I don't know it is possible or not in short I want multilevel XML based on nth node

Comment: Where is value "a" in your output? Why is it gone?

Comment: sorry but forget to mention value "a" it looks like <1> a <2>b</2></1>

Comment: You should write the expected whole output you want properly in your question. Edit the question if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to start an xml tag name with a number:

[Read this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp), region "XML naming rules"

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> - [...]
> - Element names **must start with a letter or underscore**
> - [...]

**That means, that your given output is invalid XML in any case!**

Furthermore I think, that the given output is not correct... Should letter `e` really be after `<3>` (same with `c`)? Your table does not contain any *top-level* letter at all...